# Crossfilter javascript Maximum call stack size exceeded, no Nan

Tags: javascript, d3.js, crossfilter

I am playing around with `crossfilter.js`, see https://github.com/square/crossfilter/wiki/API-Reference and http://square.github.io/crossfilter/.

Supposedly the library is very good at handling data swiftly. So to test it I first create an array of random numbers, a big one, with one million rows.

```
    function create_random_json(){
        result = []     
        for (var i = 1000000 - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            result.push( { 'a': Math.random() , 'b' : Math.random() * 5  } )
        }
        return result
    }

    json_array = create_random_json() 

    df = crossfilter( json_array )
```

So far so good, but then when I try to do some basic crossfilter things, things go terribly wrong.

```
df.dimension( function(d){ return d.total; }); 
RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
```

I've read that this error can be caused by `NaN` values but all the values that I have generated are obviously floats, so I am assuming something else is causing the trouble. Any hints?

Comment: Where is the "total" property supposed to come from? The sample code in the Crossfilter documentation involves objects that have a "total" property; your objects do not.

Comment: Also please consider using semicolons and `var` declarations :)

Comment: Looks like I blindly copied the docs. I didnt see that `total` was a property of `d`, not a function.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think you need to actually *compute* a total:

```
df.dimension(function(o) { return o.a + o.b; });
```

The function you're passing to `.dimension()` is returning `undefined`, since none of the rows of your dataset have a "total" property.